# Stratified Random Sampling Tool

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, grass-gis, random

Is there a way to produce a certain amount of random points over different classes in a raster in QGIS? 
I have extensions such as GRASS or GDAL, ...

Comment: I don't have answer but some way. Propably using r or python but for now I don't have found the best way to do it. I am very interesting by answer. Best

Comment: You can do this easily with GRASS GIS 7's v.random command: see https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.random.html#stratified-random-sampling:-random-sampling-from-vector-map-by-attribute

Comment: You can also generate random points as a raster directly using `r.random` and figure out yourself the "over different classes" part. Hence, you can avoid the forth and back conversions from raster to vector, etc. See https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.random.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible if you convert your raster to a vector layer.

Quick example, starting from this classification raster:

[image]

Use `Raster > Conversion > Polygonize` to convert it to a vector layer:

[image]

If you want to create points over a whole class (and not over each separate "patch"), use the `Vector > Geometry Tools > Singleparts to Multiparts` tool.

Then go to `Vector > Research Tools > Random Points`, select the previous vector layer in `Input Boundary Layer` and check the `Use this number of points` option if you want to create the same number of points in each class:

[image]

If you want to change the number of points depending on the class, add a column to the attribute table of the polygon layer in which you will specify the number of points for each class, then check the `Use value from input field` option (instead of `Use this number of points`) in the Random Points tool.

[image]
[image]

Comment: there is no way around creating a vectorlayer? it seems like a lot of computational power is required if the raster is very big (converting it to a vector) ...

Comment: That's the only way I can think of... Maybe someone will come with another solution, but I don't think that this step can be avoided.

Comment: Hm, its as I thought. QGIS does not finish the calculation. I can polygonize, but the `singleparts to multiparts` bit does not work... It crashes

Comment: You can alternatively try the Dissolve tool. QGIS native Dissolve might be very slow, so you can try OGR `Dissolve polygons` tool instead (you'll find it in the processing toolbox).

Comment: i tried that one as well. Same results... As I said: The polygon I receive after polygonize my raster is very very big. I was suprised that the polygonize worked...

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote: With large raster transforming the raster into a vector and then dissolve singlepart to multiparts does not work. 
There is an easier way to get the sample directly on the raster using `R`.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

# read a raster, GeoTiff or something
forSampling <- raster(someRaster.tif)

# make stratified random sampling
# set sp = TRUE to get a spatialPointsDataframe
# that one can easily be converted into a shapefile
sampleSp <- sampleStratified(x = forSampling, size = 50, xy = TRUE, sp = TRUE)

# write it out to a shapefile for further processing
writeOGR(obj = sampleSp, dsn = "aa", layer = "sampleSp", driver="ESRI Shapefile") # this is in geographical projection
```