# Stratified Random Sampling proportion to area

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a LULC raster which I need to validate using Bing map as proxy. For validation I need sample points based on the area proportion (higher the area, more the points for that class).
[image]
*Figure: 4 classes (DN) LULC*

I converted raster to polygon and tried sampling using `Random Points inside polygon` but it does not create what I intend to get. The docs also dont mention what the value signify when I select `Point density`.
What I need is random samples proportion to its size? How do I make this possible in QGIS 3.18. PyQGIS solution would also work.
[image]

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/198980/stratified-random-sampling-tool) answer does the similar preprocessing but I want samples proportion to area of each class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want [the number of] "...samples proportion to area of each class" you are referring to *density*, such as "one sample per hectare."

You're on the right track with the **Random Points Inside Polygons** tool!

To use the tool in density mode, first determine which distance units your data's Coordinate Reference System uses.  You must use a CRS that is in either feet or meters; you cannot use one based on latitude and longitude.

Next, determine what sampling density you wish to use.  For example, let's say that your data is stored as meters and you wish your sampling density to be 1 point per hectare.

**Pro tip:** Since there are 10,000 square meters in a hectare, an equivalent way to state our desired density is that we want 0.0001 points per square meter.  We'll see why this is important shortly.

Select your input polygon layer, where random points will be proportionally allocated according to feature size: larger polygons will receive more points (in our case at a rate of 1 point per hectare).

Set the tool's *Sampling strategy* to Point density.

Set the tool's *Point count or density* to 0.0001 (our **Pro tip** number).  The documentation isn't clear, but *Point count or density* is expecting the number of desired samples *per CRS unit*, in our case square meters.

Click the **Run** button and Voila! - random points based on polygon size!

[image]